# Run exe from Java args (Minecraft Launcher)

Tags: java, cmd, minecraft, args

I'm hoping to launch another application when Minecraft runs from the MC launcher so the second application doesn't need to be opened or run manually. I'm thinking the Java args could be a way to do this. Is this feasible?

For reference, this is the default java args:

```
"-Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M"
```

Is there a flag that would allow me to run an exe or execute a shell command?

Comment: I'm very confused.  What is your question?  do you want to start another program from a Java program?  What do you mean by "run a command"?  What do Java args have to do with this?

Comment: I’m trying to start another .exe when Minecraft launches and wondered if the java args could be exploited to do this.

Comment: @Mr.Technician Ok I see what you're trying to do.  I think the answer to your question is, unfortunately, a simple no.  The JVM options just set various parameters for how the JVM should run, I highly doubt there would be any option to start another program.  A simpler option would probably be to make the launcher start your program instead of Minecraft and then have your program start Minecraft.  I don't know how to do that, but it looks like you can add a new "version" in the launcher and point it to whatever jar file you want.

Comment: For a list of valid options when executing a java application see this page: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html None of the options allow when you want. You would need to manage this from within the application, or execute it separately with a script that starts both your jar file and your exe file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! Here's another idea: Perhaps I could run the launcher and launch a profile from the other application? The difficulty would be the authorization with mojang/microsoft.

Comment: Having given this some thought I think running a custom jar that launches the Minecraft jar and the custom application makes the most sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the old Minecraft launcher ([install guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/5tdrnw/steps_to_use_the_old_launcher/)), you can replace the `launcher.jar` file in your `%APPDATA%/Roaming/.minecraft` directory with your own custom Java application. Within your own application, you can do anything you like. To start Minecraft, you will have to start the original `launcher.jar` yourself. This can be done through [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-), or by including the `launcher.jar` file as a dependency in your project and calling its `main(String[])` method directly. Alternatively, you could write a batch script that starts both the Minecraft launcher and your application, or you could write a [Minecraft Forge](http://minecraftforge.net/) client mod in which you can do anything as soon as the game starts.

Comment: So it sounds like this isn't possible with the current modern launcher? Of course, it's possible to modify the game like optifine does and that works with the latest launcher from the Microsoft store...

Comment: Not unless you can modify that launcher. I haven't migrated my Minecraft Account yet and I haven't used the new Microsoft store launcher, so I don't know what language that launcher is written in and how much effort it would be to hack something in there. If I knew your application, then perhaps I could give a better recommendation on what to do. Right now you could be trying to start anything between auto-video capture software, game info software, or a keylogger.

Comment: It's a simple .NET app that can be used to make Minecraft (or any other application) run as a borderless window. I wrote the app a couple of years ago. Is it necessary to hack the launcher, though? Optifine is a modified version of the vanilla game and it can be run from the modern launcher, for example.

Comment: I also would like this to be easily distributable to others... So modifying the launcher itself isn't a good route.

Comment: For easy distribution, writing a client-side mod is the way to go. Players would have to install Forge, Fabric or another client-side modloader and drop your mod jar into some mods directory. That way is also widely accepted within the Minecraft community, as that is simply how client-side modding works. Upside is that you also have access to the entire MC client, which makes it possible to embed things in the game instead of running a separate application. Downside is that your mod would be MC version specific.

Comment: Oh, I missed your first of the two comments. It would be most convenient to add your borderless window code by supplying a mod that calls your code through JNI, or rewrite it to plain Java using JNA. In a mod, it would even be easy to add an in-game hotkey to toggle this behavior.

Comment: I may go the mod route in the future but for now I am just detecting when Minecraft runs through WMI. The plus here is the game can be vanilla and still run borderless. Thanks for the ideas though!